# Azure Synapse: Merge command with the identity column in target table is not working

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

The Merge command on the target table with the identity column gives an error although we are not updating/inserting the identity column. Please find the below snippet and error message

Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Cannot update identity column 'id'.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Sub INT, Metric INT) WITH (DISTRIBUTION = HASH(Sub), CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX);

;WITH SRC AS (SELECT 1 AS Sub, 100 AS Metric) MERGE dbo.t1 AS tgt USING SRC ON tgt.Sub = SRC.Sub WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Metric = SRC.Metric WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Sub, Metric) VALUES (SRC.Sub, SRC.Metric);
```

Error:  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is reported to product team as bug, will be fixed in future releases

Comment: We are also facing the same issue. Is there any update on the same?